# Trivial Calculus Equality: Limit of a Product

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be positive and finite functions defined for $x \ge 0$. Moreover, $f(x) \le C$ for all $x \ge 0$, and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=C$. I am wondering whether equality

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) \cdot g(x) = C \cdot \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x),$

holds. I would appreciate any explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Finite function is equal to bounded function?

Comment: Yes, both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statment is true.

Write: $|f(x)g(x) - CL| = |f(x)(g(x) - L) + g(x)(f(x) - C) -f(x)g(x) + Lf(x) + Cg(x) -LC| = |f(x)(g(x) - L) + g(x)(f(x) - C) - (g(x)-L)(f(x) - C)| \leq M|g(x) - L| + N|f(x) - C| + |g(x) - L||f(x) - C| < M\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{4M} + N\cdot \dfrac{\epsilon}{4N} + \dfrac{\epsilon^2}{16MN} < \epsilon$ if $0 < \epsilon < 8MN$.

You can fill the details to complete it.

Comment: Do we know that $g$ converges to a limit?

Comment: oh, assume it does. I am aware of the case it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, g converges. Many thanks for your answer. I upvoted and will accept it as soon as I digest it.

Comment: Could you please provide a hint for the case when g does not converge to a limit. Thank you very much.